# Strange issue with Textmate

Tags: macos, textmate

i've noticed a strange issue with my TextMate installation. I've tried re-installing TextMate and clearing out preference files but I am still getting this issue:

***Whenever I use Textmate, and command save, or save from the menu and then exit or close the active coding window, it asks me if i want to save (when it shouldn't because I've already saved it and haven't made any changes)***

Once upon a time ages ago it worked fine, but now there's no point saving it because it will always prompt me to save it. Perhaps there's a permission issue or something? I'm not sure..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having this difficulty as well.  There was a bundle that was running a command on the did-save event (Ensure Newline at EOF on Save.tmbundle). This was causing a write after save, dirtying the file.  The event should be changed to will-save, but it would be easier just to implement that one simple command in a custom bundle.

Anyway, removing this bundle fixed the issue for me.  If this bundle isn't installed, take a look to see if there are any  commands in any other added bundle that are changing the document text after save.  Look for callback.document.did-save in the semantic class field of the command.